# jQuery.scroll "listener" problem

Tags: jquery, scroll, listener, scrollto

I'am scrolling through a page witch jQuery scrollTo.
If the page reaches ssome pixels for exaple y= 300 a div slides in.

If i scroll manually i want to slide that div in too.

how do i achieve that?

I've thought about something like a event listener. jQuery.scroll exists but does'n make a difference between "manual" scrolling and "automatic" scrolling (with scrollTo).

Should i take an other attempt?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly the problem is that when listening to the regular scroll event, you don't know how far the page has been scrolled?

Try checking the scrollTop property http://javascript.gakaa.com/div-scrollleft-2-0-scrolltop.aspx.

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
$('my-selector').attr( 'scrollTop' )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar where when the page gets scrolled, the divs that show up and dissapear change color.

Check this out:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(window).scroll(function () { 


        if(window.pageYOffset >= "150" || window.pageYOffset <= "170")
        {
            $("#1").css('background', 'green');                 
        }
        else if(window.pageYOffset < "150" || window.pageYOffset > "170")
        {
                $("#1").css('background', 'none');              
        }
    });


    </script>


</head>
<body>      

<div style="width:600px">
    <div id="1">
    <h1>1</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="2">
    <h1>2</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="3">
    <h1>3</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="4">
    <h1>4</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="5">
    <h1>1</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="6">
    <h1>2</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="7">
    <h1>3</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="8">
    <h1>4</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="9">
    <h1>1</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="10">
    <h1>2</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="11">
    <h1>3</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="12">
    <h1>4</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
    </html>
```

Check this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_pagexoffset.asp

window.pageYOffset
window.pageXOffset